# Azure Mobile Apps - Overriding the QueryAsync method with custom code in Table Controller

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, azure-mobile-services

I would like to override the Query Async Method with some Custom code, so I can access an external api, get some data and then use this data to query the db tables to get the results, this should support all the default sync and paging features provided by the base method. I'm using the latest 5.0 DataSync library. Old versions returned a IQueryable so this was easy to do, but now it returns an action result. Is there any solution? Could not find any docs.

e.g. I get a set of guids from api. I query the db tables with these guids and get all the matching rows and return back to client.

I know how to override the method, call external api's, get data and query the db tables, but this provides me with a custom data format not the one that the query async gives by default with paging support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to accomplish this is to create a new repository, swapping out the various CRUD elements with your own implementation.  You can use the EntityTableRepository as an example.  You will note that the "list" operation just returns an IQueryable, so you can do what you need to do and then return the updated IQueryable.

Comment: Thank you, We were already overriding the default with a custom repository but was using the defaults for IQueryable, added a new method to apply a filter on IQueryable from controller and then used the default query async implementation to query the filtered dataset.